# AWS cloud9 pip install goes to python 2.7 instead of 3.6

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cloud9

this question is specifically for aws cloud9. Everything looks fine prima-facie, but it's creating a lot of problems.

When i am checking python version, it's showing the correct version (without using python3)

```
xxxx@yyyyy.zzz:~/environment $ python --version
Python 3.6.8
```

When i am using which python, it's showing the correct (desired) python version

```
xxxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ which python
alias python='python36'
        /usr/bin/python36
```

When i am checking pip version, it's showing pip version for python 3.6, but showing a very old version of pip.

```
xxxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

When i try to upgrade pip to new version, it goes to python2.7 now (undesirable)

```
xxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.0.2)
```

so, when i do a pip install of a desired package, it gets installed, but cannot use it in my program as it installs for python 2.7.

I have gone past this issue on my local windows computer a long time ago. However, this is a ec2 default environment that comes when setting up cloud9, and is a linux ubuntu dist (afaik).

Have tried to find out online, but couldn't get a simple answer. I could find answers relating to using virtualenv for these kind of issues. I am wondering if there is a simpler solution to this.

Comment: Do you have `pip3` or `pip-3.6` binaries; Instead of using `python -m pip --version` use `pip --version` which python version do you see ?

Comment: xxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: You will have to add an alias for `pip` to point to `pip3`

Answer (score 3):

I finally resolved it by unaliasing "python" with python36. 
`unalias python`

Then when i went to ask python version, it gave python 2.7 (as expected)

then i went for
`sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

it finally worked and upgraded pip to latest.

then i could download other libraries using 
`python3 -m pip install <library-name>`

Thanks Arun for your extensive help.

This solution may be a workaround, but it finally made it work. If anyone wants me to find the solution further, i am ready to engage.

Answer (score 1):

`python` is an alias to point to `python36`. Looks like you have python 2 and python 3 installed.

`python -m pip --version` is returning the pip version pointing to `python3` because python here refers to python3. If you try `python2.7 -m pip --version` it will return the pip version corresponding to python2.7

You should rather check `pip --version` to see the version of pip.

You could install your packages using `pip3 install <package-name>` or set an alias for `pip` to point to `pip3`

```sh
which pip3
```

Once you get the path of `pip3`, then you can create the alias

```sh
alias pip=`<path to pip3>
```

Comment: actually, i had tried using pip3, but it didn't work. checked using your command "which pip3" -------------- xxxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ which pip3
/usr/bin/which: no pip3 in (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.1/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/.......

Comment: What is the output of `pip3`? Is pip3 binary not present ? Maybe you have `pip3.6` instead of `pip3` ? python3.4 and above ship pip by default. You could alternatively try `python -m pip install <package>` this will install packages for python3.6

Comment: pip3 gives an error that command not found. However, `python -m pip install <package>` may work because i tried it and it didn't give any error..

Comment: `python -m pip install <package>` will definitely work. Try checking for pip3.6 binary

Comment: however.. now the problem is that the pip3.6 is an older version - 9.0.3 - and when i am trying to upgrade it using `python - m pip install --upgrade pip`.. it doesn't work..

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does not work mean ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip' -> '/tmp/pip-_mdcmo44-uninstall/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip'`

Comment: i tried using `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip`....... it gave this error............ `$ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.0.2)`

Comment: `python` is an alias in your case; alias is not available when using sudo, to make it working first execute `alias sudo='sudo '` and then execute `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in the same terminal

Comment: still giving same error........... `alias sudo='sudo'
xxxx@yyyy.zzz:~/environment $ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.0.2)`

Comment: what if i unalias python3.6 to python.. and then use python3 ...?

Comment: If you are okay with using python3 then it will work without any issues, you need not remove the alias